# mysql export different queries into Different WorkSheets in the Same WorkBook

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

mysql query is :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
    WHERE CId=1 
       INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql/values.csv' 
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

it works and make csv file 
but i wanna add a new worksheet to this file and execute this query :

```
select * from mytable where CId=2;
```

is it possible?

Comment: ...worksheet in CSV file?

Comment: xls files has the same problem

Comment: SELECT..INTO OUTFILE can export data into CSV format only.

Comment: No ,,, I try for xls file  ,, it makes the file

Comment: And, what did you get? Binary or text file?

Comment: xls file . with one worksheet

Comment: Maybe you openned it in Excel and saved it as XLS file. But anyway, my answer is - SELECT..INTO OUTFILE always exports in new file, so I think you should write logic in application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't add a sheet to a csv file, but you could create two csv files and use [csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sourceforge.net/) to combine them in a .xlsx file.

You need an xlsx template with two tabs prepared, then add the two csv files with these commands:

```
csv2odf -t 1 values1.csv template.xlsx temporary.xlsx
csv2odf -t 2 values2.csv temporary.xlsx output.xlsx
```

csv2odf requires [Python](http://www.python.org/).